# Vue testing with jest and vue-test-utils fails to resolve components introduced through app.component()

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Im currently trying to introduce testing to my Vue 3 Vite application. 
I am using jest and vue-test-utils for this. 
This is working fine, except when I try to mount components that contain my base components, which I introduce with app.component(basecomponent) before I app.mount("#app"); in my application.
While the test still run, I get the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: base-card 
      at <Anonymous ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
      at <VTUROOT>
```

Now my question is, what would be the best way to make this accessible to the test? Or what have I alternatively done wrong since this does not work? 
Thanks for all answers in advance :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add components on mount via `global.components`:

```js
const wrapper = mount(Component, {
  global: {
    components: {
      'base-card': BaseCard
    }
  }
})
```

Alternatively, you can include the components globally using `config`:

```js
// jest.setup.js

import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'

config.global.components = {
  'base-card': BaseCard
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@stackmeister Did you make an import of this component in your test? You can try to add this part of code too:

```
    components: {
    base-card
  },
```

Comment: Is this also necessary when using shallowMount? I still get the warning for all my components even when using shallowMount. My components are not global components.